Can't upload files larger than 8 MB on Azure App Service (Linux) with Laravel v11
I'm having trouble uploading files larger than 8 MB on my Laravel v11 application, which is hosted on Azure App Service running on Linux.
Here’s what I’ve already done to configure the upload limits:

Set the client_max_body_size directive in Nginx, and verified it's working as expected:
client_max_body_size 50M;


Updated PHP php.ini settings via PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR. Running php -i on the server's shell (SSH) confirms that the correct parameters are loaded:
upload_max_filesize = 30M
post_max_size = 50M
memory_limit = 256M



Despite these settings, I can only upload files smaller than 8 MB. Trying to upload a file around 10 MB results in the following error:
The server returned a "413 Content Too Large".

Interestingly, when I set post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 1M, I'm still able to upload a 7 MB file successfully.
Here's the output of php -i | grep max on the server:
    max_execution_time => 0 => 0
    max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
    max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
    max_input_time => -1 => -1
    max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
    max_multipart_body_parts => -1 => -1
    post_max_size => 1M => 1M
    upload_max_filesize => 1M => 1M
    zend.exception_string_param_max_len => 15 => 15
    session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
    unserialize_max_depth => 4096 => 4096

What could be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

If possible, share GitHub repository?

"Interestingly, when I set post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 1M, I'm still able to upload a 7 MB file successfully." - probably, because you are not setting them in the correct place to begin with, I suppose? PHP CLI, and PHP integrated into the web server, often use different configurations. php -i on the shell gives you the CLI configuration - but your upload doesn't happen on the command line interface, it happens via HTTP, via the web server. So call phpinfo() from within a script that you are invoking via HTTP, to verify what the actual current values of those options are.

@C3roe, thanks! I'm trying to figure out the correct place, but I followed the Azure App Service instructions to set up php.

Okay, I see. Calling phpinfo() from directly within your app is not a bad idea nevertheless; in the top section it should also show you, where it loooked for config files, and which config files were actually read. That should help to determine if you edited/created the correct one in the correct place, or might have to look elsewhere.

@C3roe, I checked phpinfo() and indeed my ini config is not being loaded even though I followed the Azure App Service steps. I will keep looking into it. Really appreciate your help !

Usually something (web server / FPM / CGI module) needs to be restarted for any such config changes to take effect. In their explanation towards the end, it said "restart your app" - I am assuming that refers to some button you press somewhere in the admin UI. If(!) you didn't do that yet, go look for where it is, because that is likely required.

Solved!
Although it is supposedly undocumented by Microsoft (or possibly a bug in Azure App Service), I added the following statement to my startup script:
cp /home/site/wwwroot/<path to your custom ini>/<custom ini>.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extensions.ini

Setting the PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR environment variable was not enough to customize the PHP settings. Therefore, I had to manually copy the ini file to the PHP settings location.
